# Random choice works but only sometimes

Tags: python, random

```
import random

mylist = ["a", "b", "c"]
mynums = ["1","2","3"]
myint = ["6","7","8"]
random.choice (mylist)

if random.choice(mylist) == "a":
    print ("a")
    random.choice (mynums)
    print (random.choice (mynums))

if random.choice(mylist) == "b":
    print ("b")
    random.choice (myint)
    print (random.choice (myint))

if random.choice(mylist) == "c":
    print ("c")
```

Now this code works for the most part, however sometimes after running; it will either execute without displaying anything, or it will pick two letters during the same run.

(I'm also new to python and I am open to any suggestion to make my above code "neater/faster". But please explain the change, I'd like to understand it before I change it.)

**edit**
Thank you all very much! you are all extremely helpful, and fast I might add.

Comment: One suggestion to make the code neater is to remove those spaces before the open parentheses that start the argument lists of your function calls. For example, `random.choice (mylist)` should be `random.choice(mylist)`. More info here: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements.

Answer (score 11):

You are getting a new random letter in each if statement. There is a possibility that the new choice won't be the letter that you're comparing, or it could even be the letter you're comparing every time. There's no way to know. If you just want to get a single random letter from the list and do something based on which one it was, store it in a variable and use the variable in your if statements instead.

```
import random

mylist = ["a", "b", "c"]
mynums = ["1","2","3"]
myint = ["6","7","8"]
letterChoice = random.choice(mylist)

if letterChoice == "a":
    print ("a")
    numberChoice = random.choice(mynums)
    print (numberChoice)

if letterChoice == "b":
    print ("b")
    intChoice = random.choice(myint)
    print (intChoice)

if letterChoice == "c":
    print ("c")
```

Answer (score 2):

@jonhopkins has explained why what's happening is happening, but you could make it a bit cleaner by putting the letter and list it refers to as pairs, and then structure the code as the following:

```
import random

mynums = ["1","2","3"]
myint = ["6","7","8"]
mylist = (('a', mynums), ('b', myint), ('c', None))

letter, opts = random.choice(mylist)
print letter
if opts:
    print random.choice(opts)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be simplified to the following.

```
import random

mylist = ["a", "b", "c"]
mynums = ["1","2","3"]
myint = ["6","7","8"]
letterChoice = random.choice (mylist)
numberChoice = random.choice (mynums)
intchoice = random.choice (myint)

print (letterchoice)
if letterChoice == "a":
    print (numberChoice)
elif letterChoice == "b":
    print (intChoice)
```